# How to make a new instance method call in a java class do nothing in unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

In the method below, how do i ensure that while unit testing that the call to
new Job instance
does nothing and skips over to other code?

```
public class TestedClass {
  public void methodToBeTested() {
    new Job("abc").start("123", "ggg"); //make this do nothing in unit test
    //other code
  }
}

public class Job {
  public String start(String a, String b){
    //some code
  }
}
```

Maybe using PowerMock, @Spy or simply mock?

Comment: You *could* (not meaning you should though) use `PowerMock` for mocking the `Job` constructor. Though a better way would be to extract the creation of the `new Job("abc")` outside of t he `TestedClass` and let that `job` be injected via constructor injection

Comment: PowerMock is overkill. You are experiencing difficulty testing your class because your class is not well designed. It is tightly coupled to Job, and when you want it to **not** be coupled to Job (i.e. for a test), it is impossible without completely mangling the bytecode with something like PowerMock. Like @Lino said, redesign the class and you'll find it's easier to test, without the need for special tools. You may find writing the tests before your implementation (TDD) will prevent you from running into this situation in future.

Comment: On top of comments above: consider how many `Jobs` TestedClass needs - then decide if you can inject Job via constructor, or if you need to inject a factory of Jobs. When refactoring existing code, you may resort to extracting new Job creation to a separate method - it is a minor change which makes the class testable.